# Data Access Service/Layer with an event-driven Firebase database

Tags: android, mvvm, firebase-realtime-database, data-access-layer, event-driven

I'm currently writing an android app and am using the Firebase real time database for it.

I'm struggling with the event driven concept of the database.

In my "normal" SQL relational world I usually implement a *data access service/layer* alongside an *MVVM* pattern to have a controlled data flow. This layer, for example, implements CRUD methods to return POCOs/POJOs.

But in this *event driven*, noSQL environment of the Firebase database the R in CRUD doesn't make sense, as I am not actively reading anything in the database anymore but rather being informed through an event that something has changed.

Can I simply replace the active reading part in CRUD with *event listeners* and continue using the *data access service/layer* approach that I'm used to, or are there significant flaws with this approach? If so, what are approaches on handling data flow with an event driven database?

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Database is used as a persistent, event-driven view model in most MVVM implementations.

So instead of building your own data access layer to map from database to view model, you store the view model in the Firebase Database and don't write your own layer anymore.

Comment: Do you know of any examples where I could see this? I don't understand how one would store a view model in the DB. To me, a view model is something that processes data for the view, not something that holds data.
Edit: still typing, i accidentaly hit enter.

Comment: I missed the time window for editing, so here is the rest of the comment:

I can currently see your suggestion working is if I give up on the concept of trying not to store data in the DB more than once. I know this idea is diluted in the firebase DB not not totally thrown overboard.
Then I have a DB scheme that is strongly coupled to a view and quite a bit of overhead when I try to keep the data in the different places aligned.
What am I missing?

Comment: Data duplication is incredibly common in NoSQL databases. If you're new to the topic, I highly recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).